# How to increase Joomla text area (WYSIWYG ) Numbers of characters or lines allowed?

Tags: html, joomla, text-editor

I'm currently using Joomla 2.5 WYSIWYG  and I'm trying to add a custom html module, but the text editor field area is limiting the number of characters allowed!

So my question is; how can I increase the number of characters allowed in the text field?

The reason why I want this is because I'm adding a javascript code that is too long to be saved.

Please help with any solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The textarea size in the Article Manager's TinyMCE editor of Joomla 2.5 is annoyingly small, especially for people used to the larger editable area that was available in Joomla 1.5.

You can change the height of this by clicking on the diagonal lined area at the bottom right hand corner and dragging up and down, but the size will reset after each session has ended. Here's how you can hardcode a height size of your choice...

Edit the file found in... plugins/editors/tinymce/tinymce.php

Then change line 723 (or thereabouts) from...

```
$editor  = '<textarea name="' . $name . '" id="' . $id .'" cols="'. $col .'" rows="' . $row . '" style="width: ' . $width . ';
height:' . $height . ';" class="mce_editable">' . $content . "</textarea>\n" .
```

to...

```
$editor  = '<textarea name="' . $name . '" id="' . $id .'" cols="'. $col .'" rows="' . $row . '" style="width: ' . $width . '; 
height:500px;" class="mce_editable">' . $content . "</textarea>\n" .
```

Replacing the height value with the height of your choice.

it may help you.Thank you